# Comparing strings in shell script not working as expected

Tags: shell

```
echo "please enter 2 word"
read var1 var2
if [ "$var 1" = "$var2" ]; then
    echo "These string are the same"
else
    echo "the strings are different"
fi;
```

The if statement is coming out as false and it's printing the else echo. I looked on various sites and they say this is the format it should be.  Am I making some syntax errors?

#### Solution

```
 if [ "$var1" = "$var2" ]; then
```

(No space between `$var` and `1` in the condition.)

Comment: is entering the words as 
hi hi
okay

Comment: No, always use quote your variables so use: `if [ "$var1" = "$var2" ]; then` see my answer below on how to use `read`.

Comment: See [How to debug a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script/951352#951352) for some information on debugging scripts — the output would have shown you some of your problems (`" 1"` clearly would be different from one of the words you typed, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Problem is this line:

```
if [ "$var 1" = "$var2" ]; then
          ^---< extra space here <---
```

Replace this line with:

```
if [ "$var1" = "$var2" ]; then
```

---

**EDIT::** To make sure you read both values in two separate variable use `IFS` like this:

```
IFS=' ' && read var1 var2
```

Comment: That depends on what values you're entering after `read`. If you enter `abc abc` then `if` block will print `These string are the same`

Comment: Add `echo` for strings + for their length after the `read` line and be sure that your strings are the same.

Comment: Print your variables as `echo "|var1| |$var2|"`

Comment: Also see my **EDIT** section.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "please enter 2 word"
read var1 
read var2
if [ "$var1" = "$var2" ]; then
    echo "These string are the same"
else
    echo "the strings are different"
fi;
```

You have to read variables 1 by 1, not in same line.

Comment: This is one option. The other is to simply enter words separated by a space.

Comment: i dont think it makes a differences but either way its still saying different